# How to model the energy (heat) dissipating from a power resistor?

Tags: resistors, heat, thermal, cooling

The issue I'm currently struggling with is: **What is the mathematical relationship between *power dissipation* and *temperature* in a resistor?**

The project I'm working on is a controller card for a [supercapacitor w/ resistive precharge] in a box.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJBVKo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistance and capacitance are known parameters of the system and the voltages are measured.  With this information I can calculate the amount of energy I'm getting ready to dump into the resistors and then decide if I have the thermal overhead to complete that charge cycle:

> `if(Predicted_Energy < MAX_ENERGY - Current_Energy)
>   {
>      charge=1;
>      Current_Energy += Predicted_Energy;
>   }`

Once I finish charging and switch to RUN mode, those resistors are cut out of the circuit.  Now they're just sitting there cooling off... dissipating energy.  How can I take this cooling over time into account with my `Current_Energy` value?  Is it possible to estimate or assume how much energy is lost given time only? Or would I need to monitor the temperature of the resistor to determine this?

Comment: Is it pulsed or continuous operation?